# How can I find out the number of pages in my Docusarus site?

Tags: docusaurus

We have a rather big site. At least I think that it is big. We use documentation versioning for some parts of it.

How can I find out how many pages do I have in the current version, and how many do I have in versioned docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days, I thought about an idea: parse the `sitemap.xml` !

---

**Step-by-step**

**1.** Build your docusaurus website with:

```
npm run build
```

**2.** Inside the generated folder `build` will be the `sitemap.xml`. It will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://your.website.com/docs/Intro</loc>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
[…]
```

If you count how many `<url>` tags are inside the file, you will have the amount of pages.

And, obviously, you can search for other keywords for your versioned docs.

Comment: Great idea! I was just playing around with sitemap today. It seems that our site has over 1100 pages.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of pages